# Using AWS Kinesis for large file uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, large-files, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

My client has a service which stores a lot of files, like video or sound files. The service works well, however looks like the long-time file storing is quite a challenge, and we would like to use AWS for storing these files.

The problem is the following, the client wants to use AWS kinesis for transferring every file from our servers to AWS. Is this possible? Can we transfer files using that service? There's a lot of video files, and we got more and more every day. And every files is relatively big.

We would also like to save some detail of the files, possibly into dynamoDB, we could use Lambda functions for that.

The most important thing, that we need a reliable data transfer option.

Comment: If you want to upload from a server you should write a program or get  a tool that leverages multi-part upload. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html  . This will stabilize and speed up transfer to AWS S3.

Comment: Thanks John, could you tell me how reliable is an upload method like this?

Comment: @sz_tech It is extremely reliable.  If there is a failure, S3 will retain the fragmentary multi-part upload  until you specifically complete it or delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KInesis would not be the right tool to upload files, unless they were all very small - and most videos would almost certainly be over the 1MB record size limit:

> The maximum size of a data blob (the data payload before
>   Base64-encoding) within one record is 1 megabyte (MB).

https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/faqs/

Comment: Thank you Brennan, and what would be the right tool for that? The most important thing is that the service has to be reliable. Could you help me with this, please?

Comment: S3 would be the defacto service of choice for storing files in the AWS ecosystem.

Comment: Yes, we want to use S3 for storing the data. However we would like to find the most reliable transfer option. We would like to transfer the file immediately to the S3 bucket, and when it has been deployed, we would like to remove the local copy. And before removing the local copy we want to make sure that the file has been completely uploaded to S3.

Comment: You can just use the S3 API and/or the AWS-cli S3 cp or sync command to copy the files - and wrap a bit of custom code around it to make sure it was recd before deleting - thats what I would do.

Comment: The Aws CP command is a bit of a mess if you want to do multi-part and really does not allow you to deal realistically with failures, so it can end up being more trouble than it's worth for large filesets.  However there are instructions from AWS premium support to do it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/).  I would suggest writing java code to handle your specific needs.

Comment: If your data is in TB's then u can try using AWS Snowball to put data into S3 bucket

Answer (score 2):

Use S3 with multi-part upload using one of the SDK's.  Objects you won't be accessing for 90+ days can be moved to Glacier.

> Multipart upload allows you to upload a single object as a set of parts. Each part is a contiguous portion of the object's data. You can upload these object parts independently and in any order. If transmission of any part fails, you can retransmit that part without affecting other parts. After all parts of your object are uploaded, Amazon S3 assembles these parts and creates the object. In general, when your object size reaches 100 MB, you should consider using multipart uploads instead of uploading the object in a single operation.

Amazon Web Services. Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) Developer Guide (Kindle Locations 4302-4306). Amazon Web Services, Inc.. Kindle Edition.

To further optimize file upload speed, use transfer acceleration:

> Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration enables fast, easy, and secure transfers of files over long distances between your client and an S3 bucket. Transfer Acceleration takes advantage of Amazon CloudFront’s globally distributed edge locations. As the data arrives at an edge location, data is routed to Amazon S3 over an optimized network path.

Amazon Web Services. Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) Developer Guide (Kindle Locations 2060-2062). Amazon Web Services, Inc.. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 1):

Kinesis launched a new service "Kinesis Video Streams" - https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/video-streams/ which may be helpful to move large amount of data.